# Vlookup the results of a Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

In the past year I have become quite skilled in Excel, and I am ready for the next step and start using VBA.

I try to achieve the following:
I want to create a tool that can run multiple `Vlookups` from different data sources, and combine all the data into one comprehensive overview.

- Step one: Run a `vlookup` in `worksheet1` using the data from `worksheet2`
- Step two: The results that are generated in worksheet1 by the `vlookup`, is the new reference data to be used in a second `vlookup` using the data of a different worksheet `worksheet3`

Now I tried to use for following code for that:

```
Dim i As Long, r As Long
r = 4
For i = 1 To 10000

On Error Resume Next

Cells(r, 9).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 7).Value, Sheets("SPdata").Range("A3:V30321"), 9, 0)
Cells(r, 11).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 7).Value, Sheets("SPdata").Range("A3:V30321"), 11, 0)
Cells(r, 10).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(r, 9).Value, Sheets("CREBS").Range("C2:D300"), 2, 0)

  r = r + 1
```

As you can see I try to use the results of `Cells(r, 9)` in the third vlookup, to match data from sheet CREBS.
The problem that I encounter is that the 3rd vlookup does not generate any results.

Also, the `On Error Resume Next` works great but I would like to fill the blanks with "Not available"

As I said, I'm quite new to this. And my method is probably not the most efficient, but if anyone can help me solve the issues / or can suggest a more efficient code, I would be most grateful.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is never a good way to code. Instead, learn how to detect the possible error using an `If Then` statement.

Comment: ^^ and using `Application.VLookup` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` will allow you to receive an error value back from the `VLookup` (e.g. if value doesn't exist) and test that value to determine whether to write "Not Available" somewhere.

Comment: OERN essentially boils down to "I don't care what happens, take any errors and shove them under the carpet & pretend they don't exist" - in other words, code keeps running, in an error state, and it's all downhill from there.

Comment: @YowE3K with proper error handling, `Resume` clears the error state. OERN doesn't - that's why you can check what `Err.Number` is at any given point

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, TIL that OERN is not equivalent to OEGT followed by RN.  (Tested.)

Answer (score 5):

A few things: Don't use `On Error Resume Next` since it is not only a code-smell (and a pungent one at that) but it will also skip past any errors that would otherwise raise your attention to a bug.

Second, never declare multiple variables on one line. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Third, you need to qualify your range references.

`Cells(r, 9).Value` is really `ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 9).Value` and guess what would happen if the `ActiveSheet` changed while the code was running?

You are trying to (inefficiently) replicate with VBA what already exists very well in Excel. For example, open up a workbook and create a Table that spans from your start row to your end row (seems 4 to 1004 in this case). Enter your final `VLOOKUP` formula there. See how it either automatically fills to the last row, or gives you the option of overwriting all the cells in the column? This is **much** faster than writing your formula in each row, and will work much better.

Additionally, since all of this data exists in other worksheets, you **should** have this data in tables, and if you *do* you can use those table names. For example, lets say each table was named the same as each sheet. Your VLOOKUP would look something like:

`=VLOOKUP([KeyColumn], SPData, Column(SPData[TheDataYouWant]), False)` and then, to overwrite errors, we make a slight modification:

`=IfError(VLOOKUP([KeyColumn], SPData, Column(SPData[TheDataYouWant]), False), "No Results")`

Trust me, learning how to do this effectively **first** will help you be better at Excel.

All you then need is **three** tables (notice how I say **three, hint, hint**) where the first table has the data to calculate, the second table creates a key in the **first column** with that data, and the third looks it up. All you then need to do is paste your raw data into your **first** table, and your populate the keys you're interested in for your **third** table, and voila!

Also, in case you missed it, your third `VLOOKUP` is trying to find the a key based off of the same key that your second `VLOOKUP` uses since a `VLOOKUP` requires the left-most value in a range to be the key for the lookup. If you can't do this, for whatever reason, learn `INDEX/MATCH` first.

And please, until you **cant** reasonably solve the problem with Excel, avoid VBA.